# How to write bash commands inside SFTP

Tags: bash, unix, sftp

I have the below script to download today's file from the server

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS='
'
SYS_DT=$(date '+%d%h%Y')
SYS_FILE='BOMExtract_'$SYS_DT'.xlsx'
sshpass -p "123" sftp "admin@XXXX" << 'EOF'
cd /u01/admin/Oracle
lcd /u01/usr
get $SYS_FILE
```

But it is not taking the value of SYS_FILE in getting command. Can anyone please help to write bash inside sftp commands?

Comment: When you put quotes around `EOF`, variables aren't expanded inside the here-document.

Comment: Why did you do that if you wanted to use variables?

Comment: You are using `sh` not `bash`. Do not expect, that any Bash feature will work in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the quotes around EOF and that fixed the issue.Thanks Barmar